# Inner Join en envió de correo

Tags: php, html, join

Realizo un módulo que consiste si un usuario registra un incidente se ingresa a mi BD y se envía por correo electrónico (no tengo problema ni con el envió ni la inserción de datos), el problema surge ya que uso tablas foráneas es decir; en mis tablas foráneas tengo mis catálogos (ID y name) y en mi tabla central solo se insertan los ID  mas no las cadenas de las tablas foráneas antes mencionadas.

Cuando se envía el correo obviamente se envían los ID que se insertaron en mi tabla central, pero lo que necesito es que me lleguen las cadenas (name)por medio de un Inner Join pero ahi el correo me llega vacio (el inner esta bien ya que lo comprobé directo en consola).

En mi código esta mi insert  y el que envía correo pero en mi segunda sentencia     `$datos = mysqli_fetch($sql);` si la coloco para que tome los valores de mi consulta ahí ya no envía ningún correo.

[image: Tabla principal donde se insertan solo los ID de las tablas foráneas]

[image: Tabla foránea donde consultan lo ID]

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 // Parametros para e combo1
   $("#combo1").change(function () {
     $("#combo1 option:selected").each(function () {
   //alert($(this).val());
    elegido=$(this).val();
    $.post("combo1.php", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
    $("#combo2").html(data);
   });   
        });
   })
});

</script>





<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 // Parametros para e combo1
   $("#combo3").change(function () {
     $("#combo3 option:selected").each(function () {
   //alert($(this).val());
    elegido=$(this).val();
    $.post("combo3.php", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
    $("#combo4").html(data);
   });   
        });
   })
});

</script>






</head>
</html>

<?php 
 session_start();
 /*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/
 if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
           $errors[] = "Descripción vacío";
        } 
  
   else if (
   !empty($_POST['title'])
   
  ){


  include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $category_id = $_POST["combo3"]; 
  $priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];  
  $area_id = $_POST["combo1"];
        $final_id = $_POST["combo2"];
        $subcategoria_id = $_POST["combo4"];
        $created_at="NOW()";

  // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

  $sql="insert into ticket (title,category_id,priority_id,area_id,final_id,subcategoria_id,created_at) value (\"$title\",\"$category_id\",$priority_id,$area_id,$final_id,$subcategoria_id,$created_at)";

  $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if ($query_new_insert){
    $messages[] = "Tu ticket ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href="tickets.php";
        </script>';
   
   } else{
    $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
   }
  } else {
   $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
  }
  
  if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="alert">&times; </button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>

   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages))
   {
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
       
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) 
       {
         echo $message;
      
       }
         
       ?> 
       
      
    </div>
    <?php
   }
   
 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

$sql = "Select t.title, 
   are.name are_desc,
   fin.name fin_desc,
   cat.name cat_desc,
   sub.name sub_desc,
   pri.name pri_desc
   
FROM
  ticket t
  
LEFT JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id  
LEFT JOIN final fin ON fin.id = t.final_id 
LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id 
LEFT JOIN sub_categoria sub ON sub.id = t.subcategoria_id  
LEFT JOIN priority pri ON pri.id = t.priority_id";







$to = 'soporte@gmail.com.mx';







$datos = mysqli_fetch($sql);

$cabeceras = 'From: ' . " " . $final_id . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";


$msjCorreo = "<img src='C:/xampp/htdocs/tickets.usuarios/images/logo.jpg'>



<center><h3><strong>Sistema de Registro de Incidencias</strong></h3></center>

<center>Para nosotros es un placer asistirle el día de hoy, a continuación le brindamos la información correspondiente a su incidente. En un momento nuestro ingeniero de soporte en turno acudirá a su lugar de trabajo</center><br/><br/><br/>


<strong>Solicitud de Atención:</strong>" . $title;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /> <br />";



$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Área:</strong> " . $datos->are_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Usuario Final:</strong> " . $datos->fin_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";


$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Categoría: </strong>" . $datos->cat_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Sub Categoria: </strong>" . $datos->sub_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Prioridad: </strong>" . $datos->pri_desc;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br /><br />";


$msjCorreo .= "
  
Gracias<br />
Departamento de Sistemas<br />

  ";
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";




if (mail($to, "Nueva Solicitud de Atención", $msjCorreo, $cabeceras)) {
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("¡Muchas gracias! Pulse aceptar, la información se ingreso correctamente y se envió por email.");
        window.location.href="tickets.php";
        </script>';
} else {
     echo "<script language='javascript'>
        alert('fallado');
     </script>";
}

 
   
?>
```

[image: Modulo de registro]

[image: Correo con los datos ingresados por el modulo]

[image: Resultado del Inner Join]

Answer (score 0):

El método POST y GET siempre envían los códigos de los .

Tu consulta esta bien pero no esta claro en que momento la ejecutas para obtener la información de la base de datos.

Comment: gracias por contestar ya edite la pregunta ya que puse el código incorrecto.